# footer div is positioning to a wrong place

Tags: html, css

html

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
header
</div>
<div id="content">
content
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
in here will be login module
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
asdfasdf
</div>
```

css

```
#wrap{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
}
#content{
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background:green;
    float:;
}
#sidebar{
    width:25%;
    height:550px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    bottom:550px;
    left:20px;
}
#footer{

float:left;
position:ralative;
}
```

I want the footer div starting from the left side(same as content and header div), but it starts with a weird point.

this is the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/64Uq5/3/

and, can somebody link me on good tutorial understanding position and float?

i think this is the reason, why this messed up, but can't understand what it means, for a newbie front-end designing.

Comment: your `#footer` style has a spelling error, 'relative'. Secondly your sidebar should have `position:absolute;` because you are using `bottom` which is a form of absolute positioning.

Comment: Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/64Uq5/6/). You don't need to use `float`, but if your using it, you need to `clear:both`after it.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/64Uq5/8/

Comment: @Mal `bottom`, `top`, `left`, and `right` are perfectly valid on `relative` positioned elements too.

Comment: @setek sorry you're right, it is messing up the positioning of the footer in this case though

Comment: @Mal sure, but the `position: relative;` is the actual culprit here, it's just exacerbated by the `left` value.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/64Uq5/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `left:0px;` in your sidebar id `#sidebar`

`#sidebar {`
`width: 25%;`
`height: 550px;`
`background: red;`
`float: left;`
`position: relative;`
`bottom: 550px;`
`left: 0;`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div style="clear:both"></div> //include this division before footer division
<div id="footer">
asdfasdf
</div>
```

css

```
#footer{
position:ralative;
float : left;
margin-top : -550px;
}
```

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ankurdhanuka/Lgyku/